# How can I save every records in derby with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, derby

```
 I was doing a java program with embedded sql database by using derby. I inserted many rows but when I selected
```

[image]

all rows I added, it only show first 2 rows I added and currently added row.

```
{
Driver derbyEmbeddedDriver = new EmbeddedDriver();
             DriverManager.registerDriver(derbyEmbeddedDriver);
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:testdb1;", "root","");
             conn.setAutoCommit(false);
             stmt = conn.createStatement();
              pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into gamedate(gamedate,currentdate) values('"+gamedat``e+"','"+gamedate+"')");//gamedate is a string,gamedate and currentdate are columns of database table
                  System.out.println("insert into gamedate(gamedate,currentdate) values("+gamedate+","+gamedate+")");
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from gamedate");
     while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.printf("%d %s %s \n",rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("gamedate"),rs.getString("currentdate"));
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. mysql and derby are two different relational database platforms, which one do you want to use? Please edit the question (and the tags) to clarify that, then you will hopefully get appropriate community members looking at the question.

Comment: It looks like you've cut and pasted only part of your program, not the whole program (and even what you cut-and-pasted contains stray random characters in it). Try including the actual code you ran, if you want more help. Just looking at your code, I wonder: (1) how many execUpdate() calls you made ? (2) Whether you did a "conn.commit()" ever?

Comment: thanks you guys. I needed conn.commit(). I am new to stackoverflow. I did not expect anyone will give me an appropriate answer. I just tried it. I will try to make next posts more formal ways.